# Как с hh.ru спарсить более 2000 записей

Tags: python

Подскажите пожалуйста, хочу спарсить более 2000 вакансий с hh, каким образом это можно сделать?
Мой участок кода, который отвечает за парсинг

```
def parser(pages=20):
    result = get_page(URL)
    data = []
    if result.status_code == 200:
        for page in range(pages):
            while len(data) < 2000:
                try:
                    result = get_page(URL, params={'text': 'Python','per_page':'100','page':page})
                    data.extend(get_content(result))
                    save_to_csv(data, CSV)
                except:
                    sleep(.5)
        if len(data) >= 2000:
            for page in range(pages):
                result = get_page(URL, params={'text': 'Python','per_page':'100','page':page})
                save_to_csv(data, './data/data{}.csv'.format(len(os.listdir('./data/'))))
parser()
```

Comment: насколько помню у hh.ru есть api... зачем парсить?

Comment: https://github.com/hhru/api/blob/master/docs/general.md

Comment: Я и делаю через api, но он позволяет выдать только 2000 записей за раз, как этот момент обойти?

Comment: @AlexandrVitkovskiy Любое API обычно поддерживает по-страничное скачивание длинной информации (pagination), так вот тут тоже должно быть в API, т.е. если первая страница содержит не все записи, то обычно можно указать параметр `page=2` или `offset=2500` что то похожее. Если нет такой возможности, тогда действительно единственный способ это делать не-через-API, т.е. качать HTML и парсить.

Comment: @Arty ок, спасибо

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению HH не выдаёт больше 2000 вакансий ни по какому запросу, ни через API, ни через браузер. Для примера вот пример выдачи по запросу: "Автомобильный бизнес": Найдено 20 420 вакансий, однако страниц в выдаче всего 40, по 50 вакансий на странице -
[image]
В документации к API написано, что максимальная глубина выдачи - 2000

`При указании параметров пагинации (page, per_page) работает ограничение: глубина возвращаемых результатов не может быть больше 2000. Например, возможен запрос per_page=10&page=199 (выдача с 1991 по 2000 вакансию), но запрос с per_page=10&page=200 вернёт ошибку (выдача с 2001 по 2010 вакансию)` - [источник](https://api.hh.ru/openapi/redoc#tag/Poisk-vakansij/operation/get-vacancies)

Скорее всего такое ограничение сделано для того что бы защититься от скачивания ВСЕХ вакансий с HH.